# Solving non linear equation in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I need to solve the following function for P and K:

[image]

I would like to find all (or a handful) of P's and K's that satisfy the equation.

I have tried using R's nleqslv package, but something is going wrong.

```
MPK<-function(X){
  Y=numeric(2)
  Y[1] = 4.34783*((.3*(X[1]^.23)+.7*(X[2]^.23))^3.34783)*0.069*(X[1]^-.77)
  Y[2] = 0.3*((1-X[2])/(1-X[1]))^.7
  Y
} 

#solve for K, P
xstart = c(.5,.5)
nleqslv(x = xstart,fn = MPK)
```

What I get is the following:

```
$x
[1] 1.214578e+10 1.006411e+00

$fvec
[1] 5.531138e-03 7.636165e-10

$termcd
[1] 5

$message
[1] "Jacobian is too ill-conditioned (1/condition=8.9e-013) (see 
allowSingular option)"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 142

$njcnt
[1] 7

$iter
[1] 70
```

How do I specify that I need solutions where Y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr1Gj.png) is equal to Y[2]?

Comment: This is an implicit function: you have an equation of form F(k, p) = 0, and you want to have a closed-form expression for k = G(p). This may not be possible to express analytically. You may have to rethink the problem that you want to solve. For example, there is a way to take derivatives of implicit functions if that's your ultimate interest.

Comment: Thank you, please see edited question I have added some information.

Comment: This helps, but only partially. Now you have 2 equations in 3 unknowns, R, K, and P. What is R?

Comment: So after doing some thinking I have re specified the question. For starters, I would like to just solve for K and P. I think it can be done with the nleqslv package as I tried doing above.

Comment: You cannot solve this the way you have written it down. You want `Y[2]` to be zero. That is only possible if `X[2]=1`. But then you can solve  the first equation for `X[1]`. A single equation.